# Eclipse not copying resources

Tags: scala, sbt, akka

Iam using akka 2.1

I have 2 issues: I have an eclipse scala project built using sbteclipse. And it works well.

But I have observed that compiling from eclipse does not copy my `resources`. My structure is:
`src/main/resources/application.conf`
`src/main/resources/common.conf`

After compiling, I do not see both the files in my target. On running it gives me an exception of the resource not found.

On compiling from `sbt`, it does as expected. But the second issue is: I have a `common.conf` file as:

```
akka {

actor {
 provider = "akka.remote.RemoteActorRefProvider"
}

remote {
 netty.tcp {
   hostname = "127.0.0.1"
 }
}
```

}

And application.conf as:

```
fileSearch {
 include "common"

  akka {
    remote.netty.tcp.port = 2560
  }
 }
```

On running my `actor` as

```
val system = ActorSystem("FileSystem",ConfigFactory.load.getConfig("fileSearch"))
val actor = system.actorOf(Props[LocalActor], "fileSearch")
```

My actor runs at port `2552` and not `2560` as mentioned. I do not know why? Initially I was using `2552` but later changed it. I have compiled and refreshed project a thousand times but still the same behavior? What am I doing wrong?

In the `target` folder I see my `resource` files containing port `2560`. But still it uses `2552`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default Eclipse only copies resources found on the *source path*. You might need to add `src/main/resources` to your source folders (right click on the folder, `Build Path/Use as source folder`. You can configure its output folder to be the same as for `src/main/scala` (something like `target/scala-2.10/classes` I assume).

Answer (score 0):

The first issue is solved by @lulian.

About the second issue, it was because I was looking at documentation of `akka 2.2` and using `akka 2.1`. This is the right [link](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.1.4/scala/remoting.html).